# Float div out of window top on click with automatic page scroll

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll, jquery-animate

I am trying to animate a div element to slide offscreen at browser window top after a user clicks on a link. This link appears when a user scrolls the page down past a certain point. When the div is clicked, the browser window animates and scrolls to the top of the page as the "Back to top" div fades out. I am needing to make this "Back to top" div not only fade out, but also slide to the top of the browser window offscreen as it's fading out. Here's what I have thus far:

**Javascript:**

```
$(function(){
    $("#back-to-top").hide();

    $(function() {
        $(window).scroll(function() {
            if($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
                $('#back-to-top').fadeIn('slow');
            } else {
                $('#back-to-top').fadeOut('slow');
            }
        });

        $('a#back-to-top').click(function() {
            $('body,html').animate({
                scrollTop: 0
            }, 800);
            return false;

            $('#back-to-top').animate({  // The part that doesn't work
                margin: '-800px 0 0 0'
                // top: '-800px' 
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: It would be so cool if you can build it on jsfiddle.net?

Comment: BTW, why would you return false before your animate code? I bet the code `$('#back-to-top').animate()` is dead.

Comment: @PulkitMittal you ought to put that in an answer, as the `return false;` definitely prevents code  this code from working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem can be with the `return false`

```
 $('a#back-to-top').click(function() {
            $(this).animate({ bottom: '1000px', opacity: 0 }, 2000, function(){
                $('a#back-to-top').hide(function(){
                    $(this).css({ bottom: '40px', opacity: 1 });
                });
            });
            $('body,html').animate({
                scrollTop: 0
            }, 1500);
            return false;
        });
```

I updated the code. It works perfectly what you are asking for. You need to restore the link's position and opacity, once the animation completes.

Comment: Yup, part of the problem was with the return false being declared before my second animate instance. I'm still having a problem with resetting this after the link animates and slides off screen. Everything is works perfectly the first time the element is clicked, but then if you scroll the page down again, the link does not reappear. Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vWLuu/ Thanks for the help guys!

Comment: @kaffolder need to reset `margin:auto` or whatever your css default is when you replace the link

Comment: @kaffolder check out the changes i have made.

Comment: Ah! That was the problem. Thanks so much Pulkit! I had one more modification I was trying to get working as well. I would like the link to ease in as you scroll down and ease out as you scroll up. Do I just need to add a `margin: '0 0 20px 0'` to the `#back-to-top` link and animate that in my first `$(window).scroll(function()...` statement?

Comment: Here's what I'm trying but it's not working and it takes forever for the link to fade in: http://jsfiddle.net/HFkLR/